# Jquery sortable hierarchyrequesterror - item disappears

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement ui allowing user to drag/drop nest groups and move items to it but no matter what i try there is still error *"Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent."*

Here is my js code (sortable settings):

```
$("#container").find(".items, .group").sortable({
  connectWith: ".items, .group",
  tolerance: "touch",
  helper: 'clone',
  opacity: 0.01,
  placeholder: {
    element: function (clone, ui) {
        return $('<span class="placeholder">' + clone[0].innerHTML + '</span>');
    },
    update: function () {
        return;
    }
  },
  sort: function (event, ui) {
  /* check if placeholder position is 0 add back placeholder */
    var pos = ui.placeholder.position();
    if (pos.left == 0 & pos.top == 0) {
        $(ui.item).before(ui.placeholder);
    }
  },
  stop: function (event, ui) {

  },
  receive: function (ev, ui) {
    if (ui.item == $(this)) {
        ui.sender.sortable("cancel");
    }
  }
});
```

You can try it [here (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/mczdc7k9/). If you move group out of container element it will disappear and there will be that error in js console.